# How to create a class that returns military time

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, time

I created a code that returns the time hh:mm format correctly, but when I use the code within another file, the output is incorrect in comparison to what it is supposed to be.

For example:

It should return this:
We wake up at 05:00
We get up at 05:30
We are sleepy again by 06:10
Last tram leaves at 23:00
Today ends at 23:59
Tomorrow starts at 00:00

But mine returns:
We wake up at 05:00
We get up at 05:30
We are sleepy again by 06:10
Last tram leaves at 23:00
Today ends at 23:59
Tomorrow starts at 24:00

The 24th hour should become 00:00 and I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
class MilClock:
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):
        self.hours = int(hours)
        self.minutes = int(minutes)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.hours:02}:{self.minutes:02}"
    def addOne(self):
        self.minutes += 1
        if self.minutes >= 60:
            self.minutes = 0
            self.hours += 1
```

''' next file utilizing code above '''

```
from milclock import *
def addMinutes(clock, n):
    for x in range(n):
        clock.addOne()
hallClock = MilClock(5,0)
print('We wake up at', hallClock)
addMinutes(hallClock, 30)
print('We get up at', hallClock)
addMinutes(hallClock, 40)
print('We are sleepy again by', hallClock)



wristWatch = MilClock(23,0)
print('Last tram leaves at', wristWatch)
addMinutes(wristWatch,59)
print('Today ends at', wristWatch)
wristWatch.addOne()
print('Tomorrow starts at', wristWatch)
```

Comment: Maybe you should wrap 24 hours the same way you wrap 60 minutes?

Comment: It would simply require another if-statement in your `MilClock.addOne` method - the same way you check to see if your minutes need to wrap around to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition of `addOne()`, try appending a similar test for the hours as you already have with the minutes:

```
def addOne(self):
    self.minutes += 1
    if self.minutes >= 60:
        self.minutes = 0
        self.hours += 1
        if self.hours >= 24:
            self.hours = 0
```